# Dynamic column Pivot SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Can you please assist me. I found the following code here on Stackoverflow however it returns nulls and I would like it to return 0 instead. Since it is dynamic columns I'm struggling to hardcode a coalesce or isnull function.
The code is shown below, please note I am pulling the data from the distance table

```
DECLARE
 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
 
SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME(VehicleRegistration) + ','
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT VehicleRegistration FROM [##Distance]) A
ORDER BY 
    VehicleRegistration;
 
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

 
SET @sql = '
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    d.VehicleRegistration AS AreaName, 
    CONCAT([Month],'' '',[Year]) AS Date,
    Coalesce(SUM(d.AreaCount),0) AreaCount
    FROM ##Distance d
    GROUP BY VehicleRegistration, [Month], year ) t
    PIVOT(
    SUM(AreaCount)
    FOR AreaName IN ('+ @columns +')
         ) AS pivot_table;';
 
    END
END
EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Comment: This has been answered a couple of times already. Create another column variable which is the ISNULL(..., 0) version of your other variable, and instead of doing SELECT *, you append that column as well as Date etc

Comment: You should in general avoid the `SELECT @i = @i + ...` type of constructs, because they don't always work. There's STRING_AGG and other modern methods you can use instead

Comment: See [antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment). Do not trust old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separate aggregation to get the columns with the `ISNULL` in it.

Note that `@variable +=` is a documented Bad Idea, you should use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead.

Also use a `date` value rather than a string as this can be more efficient.

```sql
DECLARE
    @sql     nvarchar(max),
    @columns nvarchar(max),
    @columnsIsnull nvarchar(max);
 
SELECT 
    @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(VehicleRegistration), ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VehicleRegistration),
    @columnsIsnull = STRING_AGG('ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(VehicleRegistration) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(VehicleRegistration), ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VehicleRegistration)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        VehicleRegistration
    FROM [##Distance]
) A;
 
 
SET @sql = '
SELECT
  Date,
  ' + @columnsIsnull + '
FROM (
    SELECT 
        d.VehicleRegistration AS AreaName, 
        DATEFROMPARTS(Year, [Month], 1) AS Date,
        ISNULL(SUM(d.AreaCount), 0) AreaCount
    FROM ##Distance d
    GROUP BY
        VehicleRegistration,
        [Month],
        year
) t
PIVOT(
    SUM(AreaCount)
    FOR AreaName IN (
        '+ @columns +'
    )
) AS pivot_table;';
 
PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```